# A PHP Error in Codeigniter

Tags: php

I have error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function base_url() in C:\wamp\www\apcodeigniter\application\views\inc\header_view.php on line 6
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Error
>
> Message: Call to undefined function base_url()
>
> Filename: inc/header_view.php
>
> Line Number: 6
>
> Backtrace:

It is line:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=base_url(); ?

<head>
    <title>Apcodeigniter</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=base_url(); ?>/public/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=base_url(); ?>/public/css/styles.css">

<script src="<?=base_url()?>/public/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="<?=base_url()?>/public/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

</head>
```

Comment: Line 6 is: <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=base_url(); ?>/public/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

Comment: Did you defined `base_url` anywhere within your code

Comment: You're missing the actual definition of the funtion base_url(). Did you forget to add the include to your functions somewhere?

Comment: Yes I have solved it thank you ! But there is occured the other problem like this: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: User::$user_model

Filename: controllers/user.php

Line Number: 15

Backtrace:

File: C:\wamp\www\apcodeigniter\application\controllers\user.php
Line: 15
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\wamp\www\apcodeigniter\index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once    Line15: $this->user_model->get();